# How to copy a file from one Sharepoint sub-folder to another Sharepoint folder using PowerAutomate

Tags: sharepoint, automation, power-automate

I want to copy files that are periodically added to folder: "/Shared Documents/General/Ops/Mock/" to folder: "/Shared Documents/General/Ops/Test/Mock_raw".

Multiple users create sub-folders within folder "Mock" as they add their files. For example in the image below:

[image]

Whenever a file is added, I would like to copy it from any of the sub-folders and add it to "/Shared Documents/General/Ops/Test/Mock_raw" such that this folder looks like this.

[image]

Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add trigger "When a file created" where you can put your folder. Then add action  "Copy File"
[image]